# Cannot click element using custom Robot Framework library which extends AppiumLibrary

Tags: python, robotframework, python-appium

I am trying to write my custom `Robot Framework` library in `Python`.
I am extending the `AppiumLibrary` and I am trying to write a function which clicks an element with the id of `countryGermany` from the activity.
Currently I am getting an error: `Element 'countryGermany' did not appear in 5 seconds`. I tried with `id=countryGermany` selector also, same error.

My code look like this:

```
from PageObject import PageObject

class Foo(PageObject):
def choose_country(self):
    self.open_application('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', platformName='Android', deviceName='CB512A784E', appPackage='com.example.MyApplication', appActivity='.MainActivity')
    self.wait_until_page_contains_element('bar')
    return self.tap('bar')
```

How could I click that element?

Answer (score 0):

The 5 seconds is a very short timeout, because the application has just been launched.

Comment: Even if I change it to a higher value doesn't work. I think it has to be something with the context because the element cannot be located.